# GWT Switch widget implementation (Android styled Checkbox)

Tags: gwt, gwt-material-design

I need to develop a checkbox widget which should look like an android styled Switch widget. This widget should be stateful (Should keep true-false values).

Just because of this, I don't want to inherit a whole new library like https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#switches

Does anyone have a ready made code to achieve this? A required java class + CSS change.

I have tried mGWT and GWT Material design libraries. But The aim is not to inherit any external libraries just for the sake of one tiny widget.

[image: The image I am looking for]

Answer (score 1):

have you checked [domino-ui](https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui) it has a similar checkbox/switch button and the library is really very lightweight, you can even look at the code and re-implement it, the source can be found [here](https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dominokit/domino/ui/forms/SwitchButton.java) and you can see it in action [here](https://dominokit.github.io/domino-ui-demo/index.html?theme=indigo#basic-form-elements) scroll down to switch button section.

investigate the code and copy the css if need.